# Check if wordpress archive page with all posts in concept

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code which places text in a header based on what part of the site you are on:

```
<h1 class="heading">
    <?php 
        $posttype = get_post_type();
        switch ($posttype) {
             case "tekenplannen":
                echo "Tekenplannen - " . $details[ 'title' ]; 
                break;
            case "vacatures":
                //check if we are on the archive page
                if (is_archive()) {
                     echo "Open vacatures"; 
                } else {
                    echo "Vacature - " . $details[ 'title' ]; 
                }
                 break;
            case "object":
                if (is_archive()) {
                     echo "Toonzaal"; 
                } else {
                    echo $details[ 'title' ]; 
                }
                break;
            case "nieuws":
                //check if we are on the archive page
                if (is_archive()) {
                    echo "Nieuws"; 
                } else {
                    echo $details[ 'title' ]; 
                }
                break;
            default:
                 echo $details[ 'title' ]; 
                break;
            }
        ?>
</h1>
```

This code works perfectly fine as long as my archive page has a post published. 
Imagine now that for example my "vacatures" custom post type has 4 published posts, my header title will contain "Vacatures" which is ok. Imagine now that I want to hide all my 4 posts, so they are placed in "draft" mode. If I then check my vacatures archive page again, the title will contain the text "Archives". 
Why is this not being caught by the *is_archive()* function? How do I catch this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*@Dennis*, if you are running in **custom post type**, for archive page, the conditional tag to make your content being displayed, you must use [`is_post_type_archive`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive).

```
is_post_type_archive( $post_types )
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i changed my code to this, the result is still the same though. It still shows "Archives" if all my posts are in concept

Comment: Front-end just for `publish` post status ( except single post preview ), unless you hook the query post status into draft. In default `get_post_type` will return false https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/ if post is null, so according your switch case, null will be go into **default**.